# getting error while using joins on shared hosting account in cakephp

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp

I am getting following error:

> SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 2013 Lost connection to MySQL server during query

when executing the following code:

```
$this->query("SET SQL_BIG_SELECTS=1"); 

$joins = array( 
    array( 
        'table' => 'items', 
        'alias' => 'Item', 
        'type' => 'LEFT', 
        'conditions' => array( 
            'Item.TransactionID = Notification.TransactionID', 
            'Item.ItemID = Notification.ItemId' 
        ) 
    ), 
    array( 
        'table' => 'buyers', 
        'alias' => 'Buyer', 
        'type' => 'LEFT', 
        'conditions' => array( 
            'Buyer.OrderId = Item.OrderId' 
        ) 
    ) 
); 

App::import('Component', 'SessionComponent'); 
$this->Session = new SessionComponent(new ComponentCollection()); 
$userSession = $this->Session->read("SESSION_USER");

$fetchrecord = $this->find(
    'all', 
    array( 
        'order' => 'Notification.CommentTime DESC', 
        'conditions' => array( 
            'Notification.KiOuiUserId' => $userSession['id'] 
        ), 
        'joins' => $joins, 
        'fields' => array( 
            'Notification.CommentTime', 
            'Notification.ProcessedSellerNotificationTimeStamp',
            'Notification.ProcessedSellerNotificationComment', 
            'Notification.ProcessedBuyerNotificationTimeStamp', 
            'Notification.ProcessedBuyerNotificationComment', 
            'Notification.ProcessedLeaveFeedbackTimeStamp', 
            'Notification.ProcessedRespondToFeedbackComment',
            'Notification.ProcessedRespondToFeedbackTimeStamp', 
            'Notification.ProcessedLeaveFeedbackComment', 
            'Notification.SellerId', 
            'Notification.ItemId', 
            'Notification.TransactionID', 
            'Notification.TimeStamp', 
            'Item.OrderId', 
            'Item.TransactionID', 
            'Item.Title',
            'Item.GalleryUrl', 
            'Item.BuyerUserID', 
            'Buyer.Email', 
            'Buyer.Name', 
            'Buyer.Street1', 
            'Buyer.CityName', 
            'Buyer.StateOrProvince', 
            'Buyer.Country', 
            'Buyer.PostalCode', 
            'Buyer.Phone', 
            'Buyer.OrderId'
        ), 
        'limit' => 1000 
    )
); 

if ($fetchrecord) 
{ 
    return $fetchrecord;
}
```

the above query is working fine dedicated hosting server and gives error on shared hosting. can anybody tell me solution?

Comment: Probably: use a lower limit and a loop to build `$fetchrecord`.

Comment: i have tried with limit 10.. even though it is not working.. is it the server hosting issue? or there is problem in the query?

Comment: I doubt modifying `SQL_BIG_SELECTS` does anything on a shared host - if you need that locally its because the query is identified by mysql as very inefficient. You should focus on building your data in a more efficient way, rather than changing the mysql config (on a system you don't control, by the sounds of it) to permit the inefficient query to run. Run an explain on the query and see just how bad mysql thinks it's going to be.

Comment: You can use EXPLAIN EXTENDED SELECT ... ; SHOW WARNINGS; to gain more information on what MySQL is intending to do with the query. The second result set (the "warnings") provide you the exact query/queries being built by the query optimizer.

Comment: I have found the issue.. issue is with the table indexes..
thank you all